# How to change event (hover & click) on legend item in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, charts, highcharts

You can see point value in the pie center if you are hovering chart points. Also you can see total value if you stop hovering chart point. It'd like the same behavior, if you're hovering legend item.

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
        load: function(){
            this.title.attr({text: this.series[0].total});
        },
      render: function() {
        this.series && this.title.attr({y: this.plotHeight / 2 + this.plotTop + 5});
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
    showInLegend: true,
      innerSize: '50%',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            this.series.chart.title.attr({text: this.y});
          },
          mouseOut: function(){
            this.series.chart.title.attr({text: this.total});
          },
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      y: 56.33
    }, {
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 24.03,
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.38
    }]
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q5fh1nog/24/

Also I want that clicking on active legend item will recalculate total value and show it in the center

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners on legend's elements and update the title in the same way as in point's events listeners. For example:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const series = this.series[0];
        this.title.attr({
          text: this.series[0].total
        });

        series.points.forEach(point => {
          ['label', 'symbol'].forEach(prop => {
            point.legendItem[prop].on('mouseover', () => {
              series.chart.title.attr({
                text: point.y
              });
            });

            point.legendItem[prop].on('mouseout', () => {
              series.chart.title.attr({
                text: point.total
              });
            });
          });
        });
      },
      ...
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kq9vL7so/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#on